# Export to CSV not working when page called from a master page using a cfinclude

Tags: csv, coldfusion

```
<cffunction name="QueryToCSV" access="public" returntype="string" output="false" hint="I take a query and convert it to a CSV string.">
....
</cffunction>

<cfquery name="pull_call_label" datasource="callmeasurement">
    SELECT refname, lskinid FROM lskin where isactive = 1
</cfquery>

<cfif isDefined('URL.export')>

<cfset strFilePath = GetTempFile(GetTempDirectory(),"excel_") />
<!--- Write the excel data to the file. --->

<cffile action="WRITE" file="#strFilePath#" output="#QueryToCSV(pull_call_label, "refname, lskinid")#"/>

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=report.csv"/>
<cfcontent type="application/csv" file="#strFilePath#" deletefile="true"/>

</cfif>

<cfoutput>
   <a href="#CGI.script_name#?export=csv">export</a>
</cfoutput>
```

This code is on a file called "staff-report.cfm" and it works exactly as it should on my test environment. On my test environment I only have this file. When you click on the button "export" it automatically creates and downloads the CSV file with the results from the query.

However in my real project, the file "staff-report.cfm" is included (using cfinclude) on a another file called "report-viewer.cfm", so now the file "staff-report.cfm" is called from "report-viewer.cfm" file. Now when I press the button "export", it doesn't download the file but it paste the content of the CSV file on my "report-viewer.cfm" page which is defenitely not what I want. 
I would really appreciate if someone can help how to achieve this in ColdFusion. So in other words, when I press the "export" button how can I force the browser to download the CSV file and not create it and return it to the "report-viewer.cfm" file who called it?
Note: There is no way in my scenario to get rid of the cfinclude tag and have everything on the same page.

Comment: Copy report-viewer.cfm to your test environment.  Perform standard troubleshooting so you can see what code is actually running when staff-report.cfm is an included file.

Comment: report-viewer.cfm is basely a 3 lines code page. It is used mostly as a header. All the logic is on the staff-report.cfm. I think the key to this problem is to find a way to tell browser to download the CSV file and not return to the master page. I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're `cfincluding` this, I'd bet other content has already been queued up to be delivered to the browser and the headers are already complete - it's too late to add one now without resetting output pipeline.  You may try:

```
<cfcontent reset="true">
```